# Graphic novel about an older Jason of the Argonauts fame

Tags: story-identification, comics, greek-myth

I recall reading a graphic novel recently about a group of adventurers who went on a quest to find out why the Gods (Olympians) had ceased interacting with humanity.

The cast included:

- Jason the Argonaut (now much older).
- An Amazonian who had been a slave to the King who organized the quest.
- The crippled son of the King (he had a crippled hand).
- A Satyr who was both a cook and companion of Jason.
- A Witch who was rescued by the group in their travels.
- A poet, who was assigned to chronicle the quest.
- A young merboy who turns out to be Poseidon's son.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't read them, but this sounds like "The Last Argonauts" trilogy of graphic novels.

I struggled to find a description that better matches the criteria, but what I did find does fit.

> One day, the Gods stopped talking to Men, abandoning them to disasters
>   and despair. Only one man can complete the quest that will restore the
>   balance of the world: Jason, the legendary hero who once led the
>   Argonauts to fetch the golden fleece. But times have changed; Jason
>   has become an old man haunted by terrible memories. He will, however,
>   accept to leave for an ultimate adventure at the head of a band of
>   heroes that nothing seems to predestined to enter the legend.

The cover of the first instalment looks like it matches some of the characters you mentioned to. Jason, the Amazon and the Satyr. Possibly the Prince also, but not enough detail on the cover to confirm either way.

[image: first book cover]

Comment: Yes! This is it! Thank you! Now to track down a physical copy!